# How to minimize time execution for a loop?

Tags: python, django

I have first created a list of dictionaries that contains this:

```
navs = [{'dim': object_1, 'values': [list_of_objects_relates_to_Obj1]}]
```

and i have an entry model like this:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    resp_id = models.ForeignKey('Responsibilities')
    resp_value = models.ForeignKey('JlmValues')
```

than a loop to calculate related elements for each object in the navs list:

```
for i in navs:
    for j in i['values']:
        total = 0
        list_retrieved = Entry.filter(Q(resp_value__value_path = j.value_id) | Q(resp_value__value_path__endswith= '.' + j.value_id) | Q(resp_value__value_path__contains= '.' + j.value_id + '.') | Q(resp_value__value_path__startswith= j.value_id + '.')).values_list('resp_id__mgtper_id').distinct()
        s = datetime.now()
        total += len(Responsibilities.filter(mgtper_id_id__in=list_retrieved))  
        counter.append({'type':'value','value':j.value_name, 'total':total})
        e = datetime.now()
        print "Execution time of calculating total : "+str(e - s)
```

everage Time for every Element:

```
Execution time of calculating total : 0:00:00.928000
```

i have 6 dictionaries in navs and some object in one dictionary has more than 300 related object. Is there a way to minimize time execution ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can improve it. If you're not using the result of this query elsewhere:

`total += len(Responsibilities.filter(mgtper_id_id__in=list_retrieved))`

It's more efficient to use the `.count()` method instead of using `len`. E.g:

`total += Responsibilities.filter(mgtper_id_id__in=list_retrieved).count()`

This way, they counting will be executed on the database and not on your Django instance.

Comment: almost the same `Execution time of calculating total : 0:00:00.913000`

Comment: I'd then try to optimize the DB (add indexes, see if a hand-made select with a subquery can speed things up, etc), as on that snippet that you're timing you're doing the right thing in Django.